# How can I find latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am working on `JavaScript`.I have places in array format like `["Chennai","Hyderabad","Bangalore",....]` I want to find `latitude and longitude` of them .

As per I know we can I find one place details at a time using `geocode`.but I want to find bunch of place details.For this I read `Google batch request`([link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/httpbatch)) concept, I didn't understand.

I can make API request one by one but it's not a good practice.Even If I follow same way I will get limitation error from Google.

can anyone help me, How can I find `latitude and longitude` details.

If anyone wants to down-vote, please let me know the reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Geocoder`:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, 
    function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {         
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;            
            console.log('lng: ' + location. getLng() + ', lat: ' + location.getLat());
        }
    });
```

Note that you can't do a batch request with the geocoder API. But you can use the directions api to geocode up to 8 addresses. In the business class it allows up to 24 addresses. Read about it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: What you written 2 lines of code below of code, it's very useful.Thanks for your suggestion.